# Recover partitions

Tags: windows, partitioning, mbr

I have a hard disk that was partitioned (recovery and standard boot partition) but somehow became corrupted and I only see a single partition.

Can someone recommend any free software that will restore partitions back to their original state.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of options for this, however I'd recommend this [Bootable CD](http://www.partitionwizard.com/partition-wizard-bootable-cd.html) It's ideal and will do everything you need.

If you search this forum you will find quite a few similar questions with lots of answers...

Comment: I use UBCD and found testdisk on it which worked brilliantly. 

Thanks