# Formatted linux partition from windows

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning

My machine is partitioned into windows and linux, I accidentally did a 'quick format' from windows of my linux partition.

When I boot into linux I have access to 'grub rescue'.

Does anyone have advice on how to recover ideally the partition, but alternately my data?

Comment: windows cannot read linux partition, therefore i think it's almost impossible to recover it, i love to be proven wrong though

Comment: Try looking at the program testdisk.

Comment: Not sure it does work, but you can try it: http://www.z-a-recovery.com/unformat-tutorial.htm

Comment: And this: http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-recovery/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recover partitions](http://superuser.com/questions/159642/recover-partitions)

Comment: It's not really a duplicate of the "Recover partitions" page suggested by 50-3. In this case, the *partitions* are all fine; it's the data contained in one partition (the *filesystem*) that's been damaged.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you were using a GUID Partition Table (GPT) disk, you probably ran into [this problem.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-fs-code/index.html) If so, please read that page and implement the fix it describes (namely, changing the partition type code of your Linux partition). This won't help with your immediate problem, but it will make it much less likely that you'll run into this problem again.

Second, using `fsck`, as davidgo suggests, may recover most of the files; however, it's also virtually certain that at least some of the files have already been irreparably damaged. Thus, even if you recover the partition, there's a good chance that the system won't boot completely; or if it does boot, that some random programs won't work. Thus, you may want to plan on re-installing Linux. If you don't have any user data you want to preserve, you might want to re-install Linux rather than bother with recovering the partition. If you do have user data, though, you might want to recover the partition, back up your user files (some of which may be damaged), re-install Linux, and then restore your user files. Incidentally, this type of accident illustrates one of the advantages of using a separate `/home` partition: With such a partition, you could focus on restoring `/home` and then re-install to the root (`/`) filesystem, without having to back up and then restore the files in `/home`.

In the event that you've got valuable user files and `fsck` doesn't help, using [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) might help. In theory, it will recover individual files; however, it's likely to *not* recover filenames or paths, so you'll end up spending a lot of time sifting through what it's recovered to re-organize it all. This is another illustration of an advantage of separating `/home` from `/`: When you separate your user data in this way, you can use PhotoRec on the `/home` partition alone, which will eliminate the need to sift through system files that are more easily restored by re-installing the OS.

Answer (score 0):

The answer will probably depend on the filesystem you were using (eg ext3, reiserfs, xfs, ext4...).  Certainly the first thing to do would be to make a bit copy of the partition, then try running fsck.XXXX where XXXX is the filesystem type  - which might work, if you are lucky, depending on the filesystem, and if it can find additional copies of the file table / nodes. (You might want to see if there are any switches you can use to search for alternative tables)  Failing that, try use photorec or testdisk to scan the disk and pull off what you can find based on signatures.

The most likely filesystem for a linux box is probably EXT4 or EXT3.  Look at using "Alternative Superblocks", see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-find-alternative-superblocks/ to see if you can find any and how to use them

Its unlikely that an "undelete" program would help very much, as you have blown away the layout information that undelete requires.